# Not writing to db

Tags: php, mysql

I've been here many times. I cannot get info to post to database. Can someone explain to me what im doing wrong so I can resolve the issue?

I've ran the code on a local host with E_All and E_strict and the only thing that comes up is undefined variables. Not the ones that are supposed to be posting but the username/pass/db name ones.

First is the Form I am using and the second is the php.

```
<form method="post" action="hg.php">
            <div id="box">
            <font size="1px">
            Winner must be 18 years or older and have a valid email address. Drawings will be held 12/31/2013. If for any reason either winners do not claim prize within 30 days, that winner will be null and void and we will draw again on 01/31/14 for that winners prize choices. If no winner claims their prize within 30 days from 01/31/14, all drawings and winners will be 
            forfeit except for the already claimed prizes if any.
            </font></div>

            <div class="clear"> </div>
            <div id="box">
            <label for="textfield" style="margin-top:15px;">First Name</label> 
            <input id="textfield" type="text" name="first" />
            </div>

            <div id="box">
            <label for="textfield" style="margin-top:15px;">Last Name</label> 
            <input id="textfield" type="text" name="last" />
            </div>

            <div class="clear"> </div>

            <div id="box">
            <label for="textfield">Phone</label> 
            <input id="textfield" type="text" size="13" maxlength="13" name="contact" />
            </div>

            <div id="box">
            <label for="textfield" style="margin-left:15px;">Email</label> 
            <input id="textfield" type="text" name="email" style="margin-left:15px;"/>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"> </div>

            <div id="box">
            <label for="textfield">Date of Birth</label> 
            <input id="textfield" type="text" name="dob" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"> </div>

            <div id="box"><input type="submit" value="Register" id="submit"></div>
            </form>
```

the php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <?php
            $first = $_POST['first'];
            $last= $_POST['last'];
            $contact = $_POST['contact'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $dob = $_POST['dob'];

            $host = 'localhost';
            $db_name= 'rebeler_email';
            $db_username = 'rebeler_email';
            $db_password = 'callaway87';



            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
                $statement = $pdo->prepare('
                    INSERT INTO `email`(
                        `email`,
                        `first`,
                        `last`,
                        `contact`,
                        `dob`
                    ) VALUES (
                        :email,
                        :first,
                        :last,
                        :contact,
                        :dob
                    )
                ');
                $result->execute('array(
                    `email`=>$_POST[`email`],
                    `first`=>$_POST[`first`],
                    `last`=>$_POST[`last`],
                    `contact`=>$_POST[`contact`],
                    `dob`=>$_POST[`dob`]
                )');                    $email_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
                if (!result || !$customer_id) {
                    var_dump($pdo->errorInfo());
                    die('something went wrong'); // do something better to handle errors!
                }
            }


            ?>

            <html>

            <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">

            <style type="text/css">

                #hgtitle{
                    height: 50px;
                    width: 300px;

                }
            </style>

            </head>


            <body>

            <a href="new.html"><img src="images/hgtitle.jpg" id="hgtitle"></a>

            <div id="box">
            Thank you for registering.
            </div>

            </body>


            </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the highlighted variables:

```
            $statement = $pdo->prepare(' etc... ');
            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

v.s.

```
            $result->execute(array( etc... ));
            ^^^^^^^
```

If you had proper error handling in your code, including having error_reporting and display_errors turned on, you'd have seen the "calling a method of a non-object" error that the second line would produce.

These settings should NEVER be off on your development server, because they only serve to hide errors you should be seeing/fixing right away.

Comment: thanks marc for answering, but im not 100% following what your trying to tell me to do.  Im sorry and I know I prolly annoy the crap out of ya, but can you break it down a little more.

Comment: So I edited the above code with what I think you were wanting me to do. I replace the ' with ` and put ' around the array code. It goes through but still doesn't write to database, im in the process now of learning how to put error_reporting and display_error in my code as you siuggested, anymore additional help would be appreciated so I can get this thing working

Comment: your problem is that you're preparing a statement into $statement, but then try to execute the undefined $result. It should be `$statement->execute()`. And I just noticed that the array you're passing in to the `execute()` call is incorrect. Those quotes turn the whole thing into a plaintext string, not a php array.

Comment: Additionally my problem was I didnt name the submit button name="submit"//works like a charm!! thanks man@marc

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit of a noob myself, but i'm not sure why you are using the POST globals on the variables for your database.

I'd just set them like this:

```
$host = localhost;
$db_name= rebeler_email;
$db_username = rebeler_email;
$db_password = callaway87;
```

Because you're not getting them from the form

Comment: I never said I was a noob, I guess it shows :). thanks for the info I will do that.

Comment: Note that you'll want to *quote* those *strings*.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. I meant I'm a bit of a noob on this subject myself ;) (in case i'm wrong, i need to have an excuse, don't i? haha)